# Changing text rollover rollout over an object actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe

I am trying to change a text fields text when I am rolling over with my mouse over an object. I currently have this code:

```
guide1.text = "test1"

roulette_deur.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, text_roulette);

function text_roulette(Event:MouseEvent)
{
    guide1.text = "test2"
}
```

Now the problem is, how do I switch back. When my mouse isnt over the 'roulette_deur' button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just listen for the ROLL_OUT event, and switch the text back. This is pretty simple stuff, you may want to take an introductionary course to actionscript.

```
roulette_deur.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, rouletteMouseRollOut);

function rouletteMouseRollOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    guide1.text = "test1";
}
```

Comment: Oh crap.. I opened te project again and it seemed I did not use capitals.

But thank you!